# How can I use Pan Gesture Recognizer in Swift 4 to change background images?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an app where I have a collection of Marvel facts, and I want to drag the screen to a new fact with a new background as well (all on the same view controller). I implemented a slide gesture recognizer, but I thought pan gesture would be a smoother transition (like pictures in the photo app). I've been looking for videos on YouTube and written pieces on websites, but I can only find examples of using pan recognizer to drag objects on a screen. Even a link pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You are describing a UIPageViewController, perhaps. Or simply a UIScrollView.

Comment: try this https://github.com/kaushikdas0/flat-cards-layout-ios